# sending back rewrote url without forcing a new request

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, redirect, 301-redirect

The user of my application issue commands (create new post, delete comment etc.) via links with `nonce` parameter. As this is transported via `GET` the URL bar contains this technical detail. I want to hide it and thus make the URLs user-friendlier.

I know i could use `header('Location: …')` , but this results in the browser discarding the response content and *issuing a second request* to the URL in said header. I don't want this second request to happen as it would require storing the (possible) error messages of previous operation in the session and displaying them on the next page and the like.

At the moment i use this code to alter the URL client-side

```
history.replaceState({},document.title,'<?=$url_without_nonce ?>')
```

but i really would like a proper server side solution via `PHP` or `mod_rewrite`.